# Error: cannot convert int to string while printing array values in Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, .net

Code given below is giving error that at b[3] cannot convert from int to string

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] b = new int[5] { 1, 7, 8, 9, 2 };
        Console.WriteLine(b[3],b[4]); 
        
    }
```

whereas code given below is working properly without any issue

```
int[] b = new int[5] { 1, 7, 8, 9, 2 };
        Console.WriteLine($"{b[3]} {b[4]}");
```

Answer (score 3):

`Console.WriteLine` is not well suited to just print out passed multiple arguments (as `print` in python [does](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp), for example). `Console.WriteLine` overloads with 2 parameters ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_)) require first parameter to be a string containing [a composite format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0) and the second parameter will be used to fill placheholders in this format string.

If you want to print out several items you need either combine them into string manually. For example:

- via [string inteerpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) as in your question

  ```
  Console.WriteLine($"{b[3]} {b[4]}");
  ```
- using `string.Join` (more convenient with collections):

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", new []{ b[3], b[4]}));
  ```

or use the format string:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", b[3], b[4]);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", new object[]{b[3], b[4]}); // better used with reference types
```

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine` expects one parameter to print. You are passing 2 parameters.

You can change to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] b = new int[5] { 1, 7, 8, 9, 2 };
    Console.WriteLine(b[3]);
    Console.WriteLine(b[4]);
}
```

Or better:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] b = new int[5] { 1, 7, 8, 9, 2 };
    Console.WriteLine($"{b[3]} {b[4]}");
}
```

In this case I pass one parameter with [`string interpolation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).